# Castle Windsor Complex Registration for Opened generic types

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, windsor-facilities

I have 2 classes for data handling:

```
public class SqlDataProvider<T> : IDataProvider<T> where T : IEntity
public class MongoDataProvider<T> : IDataProvider<T> where T : IEntity
```

and I have a lots of model like these:

```
public class Account : ISqlDbEntity
public class Log : IMongoDbEntity
```

with those interfaces:

```
public interface IMongoDbEntity : IEntity
public interface ISqlDbEntity : IEntity
```

How should I register or is that possible to register the Windsor container as generics but the MondoDbEntity be used with MongoDbProvider, and the MsSQl models be used with the SqlDataProvider.

```
    container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IDataProvider<>))
        .ImplementedBy(typeof(SqlDataProvider<>))
        .LifestylePerWebRequest()); //I want this work only with ISqlEntity

   container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IDataProvider<>))
        .ImplementedBy(typeof(MongoDataProvider<>))
        .LifestylePerWebRequest()); //I want this work only with IMongoDbEntity
```

I have tried these, but was not working:

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IDataProvider<ISqlDbEntity>))
                .ImplementedBy(typeof(SqlDataProvider<>))
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());

            container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IDataProvider<IMongoDbEntity>))
                .ImplementedBy(typeof(MongoDataProvider<>))
                .DependsOn(Dependency.OnAppSettingsValue("databaseName", "MongoDatabaseName"))
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

Thx in advance!

Comment: I may be missing something but why cant you do this `container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IDataProvider<ISqlDbEntity>))
                .ImplementedBy(typeof(SqlDataProvider<ISqlDbEntity>))
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());`

Comment: Thx, but this is still not working. The windsor container forces to register each component one by one, with this type of registration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This factory method works perfect!

```
        container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IDataProvider<>))
            .Forward(typeof(IReadOnlyDataProvider<>))
            .UsingFactoryMethod((kernel, model, creationContext) =>
            {
                var type = creationContext.GenericArguments.First();
                if (type.GetInterface("ISqlDbEntity") != null)
                {
                    var sqlProvider = typeof(SqlDataProvider<>);
                    return Activator.CreateInstance(sqlProvider.MakeGenericType(type), kernel.Resolve<DbContext>());
                }

                var mongoProvider = typeof(MongoDataProvider<>);
                return Activator.CreateInstance(mongoProvider.MakeGenericType(type), kernel.Resolve<MongoClientSettings>(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoDatabaseName"]);
            })
            .IsDefault()
            .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

Answer (score 2):

If each provider uses only one type of entity then why not use the distinctive entity interface in the provider type registration?

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IDataProvider<ISqlDbEntity>))
    .ImplementedBy(typeof(SqlDataProvider<>))
    .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried i(I have registered both) but  unfortunatelly this is not working, each DataProvider will be the first registration, the SqldataProvider. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can register with multiple interfaces like:

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IDataProvider<>),ISqlDbEntity))
        .ImplementedBy(typeof(SqlDataProvider<>))
        .LifestylePerWebRequest());


container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IDataProvider<>),IMongoDbEntity))
    .ImplementedBy(typeof(MongoDataProvider<>))
    .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatelly this syntax is incorect, but I thought you wanted to write this:
            container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IDataProvider<>), typeof(ISqlDbEntity))

But unfortunatelly this is not working. I am using the recent Windsor container. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

As you already did just register both instances.

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IDataProvider<ISqlDbEntity>))
                .ImplementedBy(typeof(SqlDataProvider<>))
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());

            container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IDataProvider<IMongoDbEntity>))
                .ImplementedBy(typeof(MongoDataProvider<>))
                .DependsOn(Dependency.OnAppSettingsValue("databaseName", "MongoDatabaseName"))
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

Then in the concrete classes which use this interface you could specify which implementation you want to use.

https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/inline-dependencies.md
According to the documentation:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<ITransactionProcessingEngine>().ImplementedBy<TransactionProcessingEngine>()
        .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<ILogger, SecureLogger>())
);
```

Or you can name your implementations and use this syntax.

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<ITransactionProcessingEngine>().ImplementedBy<TransactionProcessingEngine>()
        .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(ILogger), "secureLogger"))
);
```

Comment: That is what I want to avoid to register each component one by one. Is there any other solution? :)